# Extracting value from next td in a table using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, automated-tests, ui-automation, webautomation

I have a situation in which i must extract a text and select a row and then i must get a value which is present in a td right next to the cell we selected.The corresponding html page looks like this :

```
<td id='145'>
    <div> MyValue </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div>65</div>
</td>
```

I have selected the cell by using this xpath "div[starts-with(text(),'MyVal')]".I didnt know how to get the value 65 from this.I tried following and following siblings.It didnt work out.Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: Have you tried this xpath :  //div[text()='65')].

Answer (score 1):

You can do `following-sibling::td[1]` on the parent `td` element of currently selected `<div> MyValue </div>`, to get the nearest following `td`. Then, from this point you can easily return the corresponding child `div` element :

```
parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]/div
```

Comment: I tried this way as you said with regex "parent::div[starts-with(text(),' MyValue')]/following-sibling::td[1]".But i am getting the error saying that NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"parent::div[starts-with(text(),'MyValue')]/following-sibling::td[1]"}

Comment: @user2078883 I assumed you already get the `div[starts-with(text(),'MyVal')]` and want to execute another XPath relative to the `div` next. Now I don't understand why you're doing `parent::div[starts-with(text(),' MyValue')]...`, the XPath should be exactly as I posted above

Comment: @user2078883 I think the absolute XPath, if you like, would be about like this : `//div[starts-with(text(),'MyVal')]/parent::td/following-sibling::td[1]/div`